# Expression or idiom about someone who has all the news

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

What do you call someone who knows all the gossip and stories about people in his neighborhood or surroundings, someone who’s always informed. It doesn't have to be expressed in a word. Could be a sentence (e.g. she knows the ins and outs), but I’m looking for a better way to express it.

Comment: Not exactly, but you could say *sentinel* (rather sarcastically, or humorously) because a sentinel is a person who keeps a constant watch. It is implied that he is the one to first bring news of any new developments on the front. "And here comes the sentinel, he's got all the latest news."

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! You could help folks give you more targeted answers by including some specifics about how you want to use the term. For example, do you want a phrase that's insulting, complimentary, or neutral? An example sentence showing how you would use the term is also usually helpful, with a ___ or other placeholder where the word/phrase should go. Good luck!

Comment: Are you specifically talking about *gossip*? Or someone who knows gossip, but is also keeping up with the non-gossip news i.e. newspapers, news magazines, etc.?

Comment: You have asked for an adjective, but you told WendyG below that "gossip" [noun] would work "perfectly". As was suggested by your question. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: You already used the word *gossip* in your question, thereby ruling it out implicitly. If you think that word "fits the meaning perfectly," then I agree with @Cascabel that your question is unclear.

Comment: One Scottish expression - often, but not always applied to a man - is "sweetie wife".

Comment: I am surprised that nobody has mentioned the phrase [_nosy parker_...](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=nosy+parker)

Comment: how about Know-it-all or gossipmonger

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could descirbe them as being **in the know**. While this often refers to someone knowing confidential information, it can also extend to someone who is just generally well informed.

Collins Dictionary

> If you are in the know about something, especially something that is not known about or understood by many people, you have information about it.

Comment: **well-informed**. 1 : having extensive knowledge especially of current topics and events.

Comment: @Mazura Aha, doesn't quite get across the casual phrasing seemingly desired.

Comment: Agreed. It answers the title, but then they started talking about gossip. Change "news" to *gossip* and then it's probably a dupe.

Answer (score 17):

The usual saying is that they have their ***ear to the ground***.

Answer (score 10):

I would just call them a gossip

> **gossip NOUN**
>
> 1.2 derogatory count noun: A person who likes talking about other people's private lives.

This is for people whose information comes from a 3rd party, not directly from source.

You don't have to repeat information to be a gossip though, just receive it.

Comment: Thank you. It's fits the meaning perfectly in the context im writing.

Comment: @RolandHaddad I will note that "gossip" as a noun has distinct negative connotation (you can see that it's marked *derogatory* in the given definition), and it often implies that they aren't a particularly *reliable* source of news. If that's what you needed, then it is indeed the right word.

Comment: @RolandHaddad also worth pointing out that your word request only mentions that the person *knows* the information (they have their ear to the ground/they are in the know), not that they like to *share it* (they are a gossip). A personal example: I know a lot about the personal lives and secrets of people in my organization/friend group because I am known to *not* be a gossip, so they feel comfortable sharing that information with me.

Answer (score 10):

**(one's) finger on the pulse**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pulse)

> A keen awareness of current trends and happenings.
>
> Sara really has her finger on the pulse of the neighborhood, so I
>   would ask her.

Answer (score 7):

This idiom:

> She's very plugged in to what happens with the neighborhood.

From [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/plugged--in)

> Plugged in - closely connected; in touch with what is going on; informed; involved

Answer (score 5):

A rather fancy word for an inquisitive and gossipy person is *quidnunc*.

Definition: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/quidnunc

> a person who is eager to know the latest news and gossip; a gossip or busybody.

Note that this is a noun. It's also rather uncommon in modern usage.

Comment: Well I'm writing subtitles so I doubt may people would get it. Good word anyway! :)

Answer (score 3):

**[He/She] knows where all the bodies are buried.**

This is a common expression in the US when referring to a person who knows seemingly everything about everyone -- especially secret things that certain people would not want revealed.

Answer (score 3):

In New York City, the Yiddish loanword *yenta* is often used:

> 1. A woman who meddles in the business of others; a busybody; a female gossipmonger.

<sup>([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yenta))</sup>

I don’t know how well known this is outside of New York; the English-language meaning of it doesn’t really match the Yiddish meaning of the word (which is more like “gentlewoman,” I believe), and comes from Jewish–American theater (first in a 1920 Broadway play *Yenta Telebenta*, most famously in the 1964 *Fiddler on the Roof*, where the busybody matchmaker is named Yenta).

The original word is feminine, and so is the stereotypical yenta, but I have absolutely heard the word applied to men, too.

Comment: FWIW, I'm Canadian and I've never heard the word in my life.

Answer (score 0):

Someone who knows all the news can be described, perhaps a bit humorously, as **OMNISCIENT** (knowing everything about everything/everyone).

Answer (score 0):

A person who has or knows all the news is a news junkie.

A person can be gossip junkie, too. Why not?

In some context, this might fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

I recall hearing (NPR) about American words borrowed from the native language of slaves such as from African is the word hepacat (I think that I have spelled it correctly) “someone who is knowledgable about what is going on” from which is derived hepcat which leads to hipcat finally hip